# Customer partitioning in sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following format -

```
Customer_id       Purchase_date
c1                2015-01-11
c2                2015-02-12
c3                2015-11-12
c1                2016-01-01
c2                2016-12-29
c4                2016-11-28
c4                2015-03-15
...               ...
```

The table essentially contains `customer_id` with their `purchase_date`. The `customer_id` is repetitive based on the purchase made on `purchase_date`. The above is just a sample data and the table contains about `100,000` records.

Is there a way to partition the customer based on pre-defined category data

Category Partitioning

```
 - Category-1: Customer who has not made purchase in last 10 weeks, but made a purchase before that
 - Category-2: Customer who as not made a purchase in last 5 weeks, but made purchase before that
 - Category-3: Customer who has made one or more purchase in last 4 weeks or it has been 8 weeks since the first purchase
 - Category-4: Customer who has made only one purchase in the last 1 week
 - Category-5: Customer who has made only one purchase
```

What I'm looking for is a query that tells customer and their category -

```
Customer_id  Category
 C1          Category-1
 ...          ...
```

The query can adhere to - oracle, postgres, sqlserver

Comment: categories of mysql + sql-server + oracle are just confusing, please only list the dbms platform you actually use

Comment: You would also be advised to provide sample data that contains every one of those special conditions that are  listed.

Comment: The categories are not mutually exclusive, so in fact they are not categories at all. For example a customer can be in Category 1 and also 5. What should be shown then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seems that a customer can fall in multiple categories. So lets find out the customers in each category and then take **UNION** of the results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id, 'CATEGORY-1' AS Category FROM mytable GROUP BY 
Customer_Id HAVING DATEDIFF(ww,MAX(Purchase_date),GETDATE()) > 10
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id, 'CATEGORY-2' AS Category FROM mytable GROUP BY 
Customer_Id HAVING DATEDIFF(ww,MAX(Purchase_date),GETDATE()) > 5
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id, 'CATEGORY-3' AS Category FROM mytable GROUP BY 
Customer_Id HAVING DATEDIFF(ww,MAX(Purchase_date),GETDATE()) < 4 OR 
DATEDIFF(ww,MIN(Purchase_date),GETDATE()) =8 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id, 'CATEGORY-4' AS Category FROM mytable WHERE 
DATEDIFF(ww,Purchase_date,GETDATE())<=1 GROUP BY Customer_Id  having 
COUNT(*) =1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id, 'CATEGORY-5' AS Category FROM mytable GROUP BY 
Customer_Id HAVING COUNT(*) =1
ORDER BY Category
```

Hope this serves your purpose.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
with myTab as (
SELECT Customer_id ,MIN(Purchase_date) AS Min_Purchase_date,MAX(Purchase_date) AS Max_Purchase_date
        , SUM(CASE WHEN Purchase_date>= DATEADD(WEEk ,-1,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Count_LastWeek
        , COUNT(*) AS Count_All
FROM Purchases_Table
GROUP BY Customer_id
)

SELECT  Customer_id 
        , CASE  WHEN Max_Purchase_date < DATEADD(WEEK,-10,GETDATE()) THEN 'Category-1'
                WHEN Max_Purchase_date < DATEADD(WEEK,-5,GETDATE()) THEN 'Category-2'
                WHEN Max_Purchase_date >= DATEADD(WEEK,-4,GETDATE())
                    OR DATEDIFF(WEEK, Min_Purchase_date,Max_Purchase_date) >= 8 THEN 'Category-3'
                WHEN Count_LastWeek = 1 THEN 'Category-4'
                WHEN Count_All  = 1 THEN 'Category-5'
            ELSE  'No Category'
        END
FROM myTab
```